# Получить верный `text` с MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть в базе данных `message` столбец `text`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я получаю `text`, пишу вот такой код

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$getmess = $result->fetch_row();
$text= $getmess[3];
echo $text;
```

и выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы выводилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовал вот так https://www.blast.hk/threads/89329/post-753416

Comment: [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php)